# Why does Facebook's post_video_avg_time_watched returns zero for every video before June 25th, 2015?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Their documentation is here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/insights

They do say

> The Insights API only offers two years retention. Insights data older than two years is subject to removal.

But that doesn't explain why a video only a year old isn't returning `post_video_avg_time_watched` values.